# E/flutter (20289): RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in range 55277..58814, inclusive: 59396

Tags: dart, flutter

```
  List<Widget> ListMyWidgets(ticketGroups) {
    List<Widget> list = new List();

list.add(

  new CupertinoNavigationBar(

    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
   leading:
     //children: <Widget>[
       new Padding(
         padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: new Text(ticketGroups[0]['ticket_name'],style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins',color: Colors.white)),
       ),
       trailing: new Padding(
           padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: new Text('${ticketGroups.length}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins',color: Colors.white))
       ),

  )

);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < ticketGroups.length; i++) {


list.add(


new GestureDetector(
//  onTap: _try(ticketGroups[i]),
onTap: _try(ticketGroups[i]),
  //onTap: _try(1),
  // ticketGroups[i]
  child:


  new Card(

      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[

          new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new Text(ticketGroups[0]['ticket_name'],style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins')),
          ),
          new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child:  new Text(ticketGroups[i]["used"].toString(), style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins'))
          )

        ],
      ),
    )

  ),
);

    }
    return list;
  }
```

I do not know the reason why I get this error, is quiet hard to find out where exactly the error is since, does not tell me the line.
However I believe would be useful to post this snipped part of my code, as I am pretty sure this is the cause of of getting it.

Comment: Without a stack trace or line number I don't think anyone will be able to tell you any more. Could you try adding a `try catch` around that code and printing the stacktrace (although I don't know why flutter isn't printing it already...). You could also try running in debug mode and breaking on all uncaught dart exceptions (look up how to do that for intelliJ as it's probably the easiest). That being said, I can't see anything obvious unless it's something to do with the strings you're reading from ticketGroups (maybe an unsupported character?)